# partial class with interface with it

Tags: mvvm, partial-classes

I am having two namespaces with two classes with same Name something like this "public partial class CustomerDetail" one from "namespace MS.Client" which implements "IClient" Interface and another one from "namespace MS.Customer" which implements "ICustomerInfo" Interface  both in different assembly as well. am trying to access "CustomerDetail" from some other "namespace MS.Applications.View" which has a reference for "namespace MS.Client" but when I suppose to instantiate the  "CustomerDetail" class in "namespace MS.Applications.View" I would except all the properties that belongs to "CustomerDetail" in all the namespaces correct? but it was not actually working. can any one help me out from this?

```
namespace MS.Client
{
    public partial class CustomerDetail : IClient
    {
        private string name;

        public string CustName
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        private string address;

        public string CustAddress
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

---

```
namespace MS.Customer
{
    public partial class CustomerDetail : ICustomerInfo
    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        private string address;

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

---

please let me know if any one cant understand my summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, classes are local to their namespaces and thus, you can not modify a class from a different namespace. All classes have a fully qualified name, which is their real name, and the namespace is part of it.

What you are actually doing in your code is defining two different `CustomerDetail` classes, each in a different namespace, effectively being: `MS.Customer.CustomerDetail` and `MS.Client.CustomerDetail`.

In order to achieve what you are trying, you need to change to change one of the namespaces so they actually match and the `CustomerDetail` are actually the same (i.e. they have the same fully qualified name since they are prefixed by the same namespace and have the same name).